# Finding the first value greater than in a SortedMap

Tags: java, guava, sortedmap

I'd like to know what is there a better way to find the first value greater than an inputted value in a large SortedMap instead of looping through all values in my example below. Or if SortedMap is a the best structure to use for this.

Could this be achieved using google-collections?
Thanks in advance

```
public class mapTest {
public static void main(String[] args) {

SortedMap<Double, Object> sortedMap = new TreeMap<Double, Object>();
    sortedMap.put(30d, "lala");     
    sortedMap.put(10d, "foo");
    sortedMap.put(25d, "bar");
    System.out.println("result: " + findFirstValueGreaterThan(sortedMap, 28d));
}

public static Object findFirstValueGreaterThan(SortedMap<Double, Object> sortedMap, Double value) {
    for (Entry<Double, Object> entry : sortedMap.entrySet()) {
        if (entry.getKey() > value) {
            // return first value with a key greater than the inputted value
            return entry.getValue();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's all in the docs:

[ceilingKey(K key)

    Returns the least key greater than or equal to the given key, or null if there is no such key.](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#ceilingKey(K))

So,

```
findFirstValueGreaterThan(sortedMap, 28d)
```

should be

```
sortedMap.ceilingKey(28d)
```

Pay attention at difference between "greater than" and "greater than or equal to", though.

Comment: strictly speaking, `ceilingKey` and similar methods are in the `NavigableMap` interface, not the `SortedMap` interface.

Comment: @Stephen Thanks, my bad. I'll leave the answer since TreeMap is mentioned in the question (and all standard SortedMap implementations are also NavigableMap implementations anyway).

Answer (score 2):

This solution only requires SortedMap. Please note that tailMap typically doesn't create a new map, so it's fast.

```
public static <K extends Comparable<K>, V> V
        findFirstValueGreaterThan(SortedMap<K, V> map, K value) {
    Iterator<Entry<K, V>> it = map.tailMap(value).entrySet().iterator();
    if (it.hasNext()) {
        Entry<K, V> e = it.next();
        if (e.getKey().compareTo(value) > 0) {
            return e.getValue();
        } else if (it.hasNext()) {
            return it.next().getValue();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: thanks thomas, ceilingKey looks better suited for my use case